# Efficiently store multiple keys in one category

Tags: database-design

I am using MySQL database and JSP for a project. In my project there are categories like Philosophy, Technical, Art, Sports etc. These categories have multiple values like sports have hockey, cricket, football, etc. If I use a database to store this values, redundancy will occur.
e.g. sport-cricket,sport-hockey etc.

So my question is, Is there any efficient way to store these values so that when any person enter a cricket it compares with cricket in sports category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a classic [many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29).

A `category` can have many `value` records, and a `value` can be associated with many `category` records.

To model this, you would create three tables: `category`, `value`, and a junction table, `category_value`.

**Category**

- ID
- Name
- Etc...

**Value**

- ID
- Name
- Etc...

**Category_Value**

- CategoryID
- ValueID

Answer (score 0):

Your typical DBMS doesn't understand the concept of "pointer", so in order to "relate" two tables, some values from one table must be physically copied to another. Also, whenever you create an index, a copy of the data from the indexed columns will be stored in that index.

There are very good reasons why there are no pointers in the databases. Most notably, the DBMS can move the data around within the physical storage without worrying about hanging pointers. This alone is well worth the somewhat increased storage requirements (over a hypothetical DBMS using pointers instead of copies), so you'll just have to live with it.

---

That being said, **do normalize** your data. The [Michael Fredrickson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10001009/533120) already covered the M:N relationship, but in case this is actually 1:N (i.e. a value cannot be in more than one category), you'd need something like this:

[image]